# LLIllegalOperationException in Livelink

Tags: c#-4.0, livelink

I have LiveLink or Opentext server verison 10.0.0 and Livelink Client Version 9.5.0. I wish to extract document from server using C# programming. I extracted some documents from server but I got following exception only few documents:

LLIllegalOperationException: get(name) not implemented for this datatype
at com.opentext.api.LLInstance.get(String name) at com.opentext.api.LLValue.toString(String name)

It works in Livelink Server version 9.2.0 with same code.
Anybody help me to fix this issue? 
Thanks in advance
Shyam

Comment: Are you using LAPI or ELAPI on the client side? If so you should consider the Web Services as LAPI is not recommended anymore and not 64 bit safe (yet).

Comment: Actually, I am using LAPI.

Comment: Any chance to move to Web Services? As far as I understand SOAP call are well supported on MS's C# platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenText Enterprise WebService instead of LAPI which is obsolete.

We have DocumentManagement Service for download document from Content Server.